# jsfl move .jpg .png to different folders

Tags: flash, png, jpeg, jsfl

I was wondering if it is possible to move a library items based on their extensions.

I know that bitmaps can be moved using this code:

```
if(myItemType == "bitmap"){
mylibrary.moveToFolder("Bitmaps", myItemName, true);
```

Source: http://www.flashperfection.com/tutorials/Organizing-Library-using-JSFL-36522.html

---

However: my question is weather it is possible to move items containing, for example, ".jpg" and ".png", and move the items to two different folders named "JPGs" and "PNGs."

For this job I am doing the client requires PNG and JPG files to be in separate folders in the Flash library.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

-PAT

Comment: isn't it a matter of checking the extension rather than the item type ? `var ext = myItemName.substr(myItemName.lastIndexOf("."));
mylibrary.moveToFolder(ext == ".jpg" ? "JPGs" : "PNGs", myItemName, true); ` or something along these lines ?

Comment: This is great! I'm able to move jpg extensions with this. But what would this look like in an if else statement?

Comment: I'm totally new to this, So bear with me. I guess I don't understand how the code looks for extensions. For example: If(myItemName == ".jpg"){mylibrary.moveToFolder("JPGs")}else{ If(myItemName == ".png"){mylibrary.moveToFolder("PNGs")}

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code above it should a matter of extracting the extension by a sub-string from the last `.` character found in the string until the end of the string using something like [substr()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp):

```
var extension = myItemName.substr(myItemName.lastIndexOf("."));//grab the extension from the name
if(extension.toLowerCase() == ".jpg") mylibrary.moveToFolder("JPGs", myItemName, true);//move to folder based on extension
if(extension.toLowerCase() == ".png") mylibrary.moveToFolder("PNGs", myItemName, true);
//...etc.
```

if you like you can use a [switch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) statement instead of the `if` conditional:

```
switch(extension)
{
    case ".jpg":
    case ".JPG":
      mylibrary.moveToFolder("JPGs", myItemName, true);
      break;
    case ".png":
    case ".PNG":
      mylibrary.moveToFolder("PNGs", myItemName, true);
      break;
    //...etc.
}
```